# Add AppExchange app dependency in sfdx-project.json

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, salesforce-support

We are trying to build up a scratch org with sfdx-project.json file. Post that we are deploying all the live code to it from git. Now during the code deploy, we are facing issues due to the fact that few AppExchange apps deployed in prod are missing from scratch org.

Is there any feature/setting in the sfdx-project.json file to deploy specific/all AppExchange apps in scratch org which are deployed in Production?

Comment: Check installedpackages, you can refer to the metadata api’s documentation

Comment: @glls - Sorry but didn't found any quick guidance over it... Any references to include in config file

Comment: Its not in the config file, its in the project default folder - you should really check the metadata api documentation.  I’m on mobile, so i cant provide a complete answer atm.

Answer (score 0):

The comments from glls are referring you to the Metadata API's [`InstalledPackage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm#!) entity. You can construct a Metadata API deployment composed exclusively of these entities, which define the version number and namespace of the package you wish to install, as a step prior to pushing your code.

The XML metadata looks like this (from the documentation above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InstalledPackage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
<password>optional_password</password>
<activateRSS>true</activateRSS>
</InstalledPackage>
```

Note that

> You can’t deploy a package along with other metadata types. When you deploy InstalledPackage, it must be the only metadata type specified in the manifest file.

so what you'd probably want to do is build a separate directory with your `InstalledPackage` files and run `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` against it to request the installation of those packages in your org prior to your SFDX push.

Alternately, you can script the CLI via the `sfdx force:package:install --package 04t...` command, but you'll need the `04t` package version Id for each package you wish to install.